# How not to push a given commit

Tags: mercurial

I accidentally committed some huge files (300MB). Then I made other commits, and realized that the huge files should not go into the repository, so I deleted them.

However, when pushing, mercurial tries to send the changesets chronologically, which means it first tries to push the huge files. Which didn't succeed after 2 hours of waiting. So, can I get rid of that particular commit(changeset) without affecting the rest?

Or I should delete the whole project, pull a fresh copy and re-apply my other changes manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to re-apply your other changes entirely manually. You can `export` them and then `import` them to your fresh repository copy.

Answer (score 2):

I usually find that the `rebase` and `strip` commands are very useful tools for this kind of history modification operation; you can rebase all your changes made after the bad commit on top of its parent, and then strip the bad changeset.

Say `<bad>` is the bad changeset that you want to remove, `<parent>` is its parent and `<child>` is the child which you want to keep:

```
hg rebase -s <child> -d <parent>
hg strip <bad>
```

Example:

```
$ hg log -G
@  changeset:   2:6d0685591967
|  summary:     after
|
o  changeset:   1:fab6b3f4effa
|  summary:     bad
|
o  changeset:   0:0233d1f3547c
   summary:     before

$ hg rebase -s 2 -d 0
saved backup bundle to .hg/strip-backup/6d0685591967-backup.hg
$ hg log -G
@  changeset:   2:b0fa9ee8533f
|  parent:      0:0233d1f3547c
|  summary:     after
|
| o  changeset:   1:fab6b3f4effa
|/   summary:     bad
|
o  changeset:   0:0233d1f3547c
   summary:     before

$ hg strip 1
saved backup bundle to .hg/strip-backup/fab6b3f4effa-backup.hg
$ hg log -G
@  changeset:   1:b0fa9ee8533f
|  summary:     after
|
o  changeset:   0:0233d1f3547c
   summary:     before
```

As you can see, the bad changeset is now gone.

Note that for `rebase` and `strip` to work you need to enable the `rebase` and `mq` extensions. Also be sure to make a backup copy of your repository before performing this history modifying operation.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the push didn't complete, you can try enabling the "mq" extension and you can delete a commit that hasn't been pushed.

Comment: tried that, but it f*cked up the entire local repository. I got pissed and manually copied the changed files, deleted the project, pulled a fresh copy and applied manually..

Comment: Yeah, doesn't always work depending on how your repo looks and what you have connected to that commit.